# How to fill formula output across columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `Stockhistory` function in excel and getting data for last 7 days , which is populating an array into single column A2:A6.
Instead of this I want to fill data in columns B1  to F1.  Here each column B1:F1 represent a date header.

Comment: Use `Transpose()` function.

Comment: =TRANSPOSE(STOCKHISTORY(A1,TODAY()-7, TODAY(),0, 1,1))  yes it is working.

Comment: Glad to know! I have posted as answer so that you can accept and thread can be treated as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Transpose()` function to transpose data from column `A2:A6` to row `A2:A6`. Use Transpose like-

```
=TRANSPOSE(STOCKHISTORY(...))
```